# Redis data structure: key -> field -> list of values Is this possible?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

Is it possible to store data in the following structure in Redis(using Jedis)?

```
key
 |-fieldA
 |   |-value1
 |   |-value2
 |   |-value3
 |
 |-fieldB
     |-value4
     |-value5
     |-value6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis doesn't technically support the data structure you want. There are a few workarounds; a simple one is to create a separate list for each field, making the redis key a combination of your key and the specific field. For example:

```
LPUSH key:fieldA value1 value2 value3
LPUSH key:fieldB value4 value5 value6
```

Another approach is to use a hash, with a serialized form for your values:

```
HSET key fieldA "value1,value2,value3"
HSET key fieldB "value4,value5,value6"
```

This makes it less convenient to add and remove individual values, but provides the additional functionality of a unified hash.